# compare and hide in drop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a drop downmenu on a page, after users add a content to the db,
i do not want the specific value that was added
from the dorpdown menu to show in the list again.
I do not want to delete that specific value from the dropdown table.
Your help will do.

Here is my code below:

```
    <?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM vreg_no order by vreg desc";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{{
$_SESSION['svregx'] = $row['vreg'];
}}
?>
<select name="svreg" class="bodytxt" id="svreg">
<option>Select Vehicle #</option>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM vreg_no order by vreg desc";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{{
$vreg = $row['vreg'];
if($_SESSION['svregx'] == $vreg){
//do nothing
}
elseif($_SESSION['svregx'] != $vreg){
echo"<option value='$vreg'>$vreg</option>";
}else{}
}}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: soooooo... you question is???

Comment: I'm confused exactly what you mean.  You have values from your DB in a dropdown menu.  If someone adds an item to the db from the dropdown menu you don't  want it to appear in the dropdown but you don't want to delete it?  is that right?

Comment: i understand why you should be confused,you see, i don't want to be adding that to the db every time someone makes an entry.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing the same query twice.

The first one should be something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM vreg_no WHERE user_id = YOUR_USER_ID";
```

or probably a join depending on your database structure.

Than you can add all values to an array and use something like `in_array` to check if this value exists for a certain user.

And you should dump the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and switch to prepared statements with bound variables in PDO or mysqli.

Comment: i select * from a table call vehicle_info.In my dropdown menu,I have vehicle registration #s in it.When an entry is made,the vehicle registration #s is entered in to vehicle_info.Am trying to avoid the case where i don't have to use that same vehicle registration #s from the dropdown menu to make another entry again.Deleting it from where i populate dropdown menu,then i will have to populate it all the time.
Am trying to compare the vehicle reg #s that i select from vehicle_info table with the reg #s in dropdown menu on the same page,if its the same don't echo,else echo it.App have one user.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is not producing duplicate user generated content, wouldn't it just be an issue of issuing a DISTINCT query?

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT vreg FROM vreg_no order by vreg desc";
```